# How to right click in Vimperator?

Tags: firefox, vimperator

Mouseless browsing is great, hints are great. Is there a way to right click, without using the mouse?

Comment: My keyboard has a context menu key next to the right `control` key, which basically right-clicks for me via keyboard. Lemme go check if my other ones do...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
;c
```

Allows you to open the right click menu (also called the contextual menu) for links.

I'm not aware of any other ways to trigger this menu for other areas of the page and browser.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to previous answers: if you're on Linux/Unix OS, try out [KeyNav](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/keynav/). This program allows you to move cursor quickly without mouse - it also allows you to press buttons via key presses.

Ties nicely with Vimperator / Pentadactyl, must say.